MudBlazor - MudAutocomplete opens the list on load, stealing focus
As in the title, upon loading the component opens the list of available search items stealing focus.
Here is a reproduction of the issue: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOGSYNwqReIIifvX
I tried changing the parameters (e.g. AutoFocus=false) and using a MudFocusTrap but neither seemed to work. I expect the list to open only on click, not on page load.

your snippet doesn't work at all

@SergShevchenko it seems to work for me, could you please clarify what you mean?

yes my bad. I found issue if you remove Text="@SearchProductName"  all works. Try to get entered text different way

remove Text="@SearchProductName" all works.
you have
private void SearchTextChanged(string productName)
{
    SearchProductName = productName;
    //call search event in singleton service
}

 

to reflect change to model. Or try to find different way to bind
